# The value of AsyncLocal is not correct when is set from an asynchronous method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

Why the value of an `AsyncLocal` field is not preserved when is set from an asynchronous method of a class. Consider this example:

```
var scope = new TestScope();

// The default value is 0
Console.WriteLine(scope.Counter.Value);

// Setting the vlaue to 2
await scope.SetValueAsync();

Console.WriteLine(scope.Counter.Value);

class TestScope
{
    public readonly AsyncLocal<int> Counter = new AsyncLocal<int> { Value = 0 };

    public async Task SetValueAsync()
    {
        this.Counter.Value = 2;

        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

The expected output should be:

`0`

`2`

But the actual is:

`0`

`0`

Why the async context is changed when exiting the `SetValueAsync` method?

Comment: See J. Andrew Laughlin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232514/why-does-asynclocalt-return-different-results-when-code-is-refactored-slightly)

Comment: Yes. I found out the reason in the post. But, is there any solution to wrap an `AsyncLocal` field in a class?

Comment: `AsyncLocal<T>` is for passing values *down*. It's not intended to *return* values *up*. While you can hack in a mutable wrapper, I wouldn't recommend it. That could easily cause other sharing problems in more complex scenarios. It's much better to only use `AsyncLocal<T>` to pass values down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because AsyncLocal has copy-on-write semantics. Basically, when changed from an inner async scope, a copy of the value is made and the original object isn't modified.

You can get around this by wrapping your value in a reference object. That's because even if you make a copy of a reference, you're still manipulating the same object in the end:

```
class TestScope
{
    public readonly AsyncLocal<StrongBox<int>> Counter = new AsyncLocal<StrongBox<int>> { Value = new StrongBox<int>(0) };

    public int Value
    {
        get => Counter.Value.Value;
        set => Counter.Value.Value = value;
    }

    public async Task SetValueAsync()
    {
        this.Value = 2;

        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

static async Task Test()
{
    var scope = new TestScope();

    // The default value is 0
    Console.WriteLine(scope.Value);

    // Setting the value to 2
    await scope.SetValueAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(scope.Value);
}
```

[`StrongBox<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003493) is just a convenient way to wrap a value type inside of a reference type. But any other reference type would have done the trick.